# How to get mp3 file uri and play it in android programatically

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I want to make a application in which i play the .mp3 file
i play the sound by selecting it from raw or asset folder which is hard coded in code.
But i want that user pick any mp3 file anywhere from their android phone and make play it

Can any one help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715003/simple-mediaplayer-play-mp3-from-file-path

Comment: jakozo thanks for ur reply
but i want that user can pick mp3 file anywhere from their phone

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);

mediaPlayer.start();
int duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
int current_position = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

mediaPlayer.pause();
```

Great tutorial on Media Playback through MediaPlayer:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_mediaplayer.htm