# How to play music by its uri

Tags: android, mp3, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to retrieve the music data  saving the data into an array list and converting the data string into uri and using it to play the music but the app crash when ever I click. list view item it will play the music by its uri
here is my code `

```
public class Mediafileinfo {
private String title;
private String artist;
private String data;
public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

`
this  is the class where i am saving my media data 
and i am trying to play like this
where i am doing wrong

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Mediafileinfo item = new Mediafileinfo();
            Uri myUri = Uri.parse(item.getData());
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(myUri));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```

my main activity class were i am getting the data

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    External();
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new CustomeAdapter(this, audioList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Mediafileinfo item = new Mediafileinfo();
            Uri myUri = Uri.parse(item.getData());

            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            mediaPlayer.reset();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.this,myUri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();

        }
    });
}

private void External() {
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};// Can include more data for more details and check it.

        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + ">=90000";

        String[] selectionArgs = null;

        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";

        Cursor audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

        if (audioCursor != null) {
            if (audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    int audioTitle = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                    int audioartist = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
                    int audioalbum = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
                    int audiodata= audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
                    Mediafileinfo info = new Mediafileinfo();
                    info.setData(audioCursor.getString(audiodata));
                    info.setTitle(audioCursor.getString(audioTitle));
                    info.setAlbum(audioCursor.getLong(audioalbum));
                    info.setArtist(audioCursor.getString(audioartist));
                    audioList.add(info);
                } while (audioCursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        audioCursor.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

my custome adapter

```
public class CustomeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
public CustomeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Mediafileinfo> audioList) {
    super(context,R.layout.custome,audioList);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflate=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View v=inflate.inflate(R.layout.custome,parent,false);
    Mediafileinfo item = (Mediafileinfo) getItem(position);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    text1.setText(item.getData());
    TextView text2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    text2.setText(item.getArtist());
    TextView text3=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    text3.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(item.getAlbum()),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(item.getAlbum()) -
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(item.getAlbum()))));

    return v;
}
}
```

In this way i am getting the data and how i can play it when item clicked

Comment: Whats the error log?

Comment: java null point exception uri string

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715003/simple-mediaplayer-play-mp3-from-file-path)

Comment: but what if i  get the uri from the internal storage

Comment: @SAVVY can you show us the value of `item.getData()`?

Comment: I am retrieving  the media data using cursor and using that string to save it in the method set string and when ever the user click the list I want to use the uri of that position to play the music

Comment: @SAVVY check my answer and comment if have any issue.

Comment: i am saving the retrived data into a arraylist and using method to call the data is this a problem ??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.this,myUri);` instead of `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(myUri));`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //Mediafileinfo item = new Mediafileinfo();
            Mediafileinfo item = audioList.get(i);
            Uri myUri = Uri.parse(item.getData());
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
               // mediaPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(myUri));
               mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.this,myUri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: still getting error like java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString and its showing there is some error in the on item click

Comment: can post logcat here? and what is `Mediafileinfo`?

Comment: you are creating `Mediafileinfo` object and then getting `getData()` from it. i think your item is null because you are creating it now?

Comment: i am able to display the data in my list view

Comment: i m putting my hole code hope that will help u to find my error

Comment: is your issue fixed?

Comment: thx it worked,So you r just putting the array list position so the method will only use the audio data position

Comment: i voted up but my vote will not count till my reputation is more than 15

Comment: I am able to play the music but when i press other position they also start playing

Comment: @SAVVY now you should debug and check the issue or post an other question with you new problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
try {
   Uri myUri = Uri.parse(item.getData());
   Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
   r.play();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I solved this with the following logic:

use this:

```
SetDataSourc(context, uri)
```

instead of this:

```
setDataSource(uri)
```

and for this solution you don't need to read permission in above = Q

Answer (score -1):

you should init MediaPlayer one time

and add mediaPlayer.reset befor mediaPlayer.setDataSource(String.valueOf(myUri))

try this may resolve your problem

Comment: Please avoid adding answers that you have not tested. This is evident as the OP says it is not working.