# How to get the full path Mp3 songs from internal storage?

Tags: android

I want to implement a simple Media Player.How can i retrieve the full path of Mp3 songs from internal storage in android.

Comment: any efforts form your side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mpintro = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/Music/intro.mp3"));
mpintro.setLooping(true);
        mpintro.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have any problem search first. do your efforts you'll find it...
here's a link try it [Get Mp3 from SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715003/simple-mediaplayer-play-mp3-from-file-path)

Comment: @ Shashank Verma i want to fetch the file path from device internal storage not from SD card.

Answer (score 1):

Try this check for file if it exists or not

```
  public static String rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/YourDirectory/";       

 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/YourDirectoryFolder/Audio/" + NmaeofFile + "/");
    if (!file.exists())
        return false;
    else{
        //Do your work here
         }
```

And then simply start media player

```
player.setDataSource(rootPath);//rootpath is the path of your file
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
```