# playing mp3 file in second activity after button is clicked

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

hello I am very new to android programming.I want Button in first activity and when it is clicked second activity will open and plays mp3 file from sd card i have mention path but mp3 file not plays after running project.I am posting my player.java

This is my class

```
public class player extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btPv,btplay,btStop,btPause;
SeekBar sb;
MediaPlayer mp3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
    ;
    btplay=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btplay);
    btStop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btstop);
    btPause=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btpause);
    mp3=new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mp3.setDataSource("sdcard/musicblee/Over_the_horizon.mp3");
        mp3.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    btplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp3.start();

        }
    });
    btStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                mp3.stop();
                mp3.reset();
                mp3.setDataSource("sdcard/musicblee/Over_the_horizon.mp3");
                mp3.prepare();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    btPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                mp3.pause();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}




}
```

Comment: Try changing mp3.setDataSource("sdcard/musicblee/Over_the_horizon.mp3"); to mp3.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/musicblee/Over_the_horizon.mp3");

Comment: Also I would suggest you to move the entire try catch block in the onclicklistenr of the start button

Answer (score 0):

refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715003/simple-mediaplayer-play-mp3-from-file-path) use `mp3.setDataSource()` like that

```
mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/musicblee/Over_the_horizon.mp3"));
```

to set mp3 source.
And Also add this permission to your Android Manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: after inserting this line                                                                                
 final String path=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getPath()+"/Musicblee/Over_the_horizone";    get error unfortunately app stops

Comment: final String path=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getPath()+"/Musicblee/Over_the_horizon.mp3";

Comment: storage/extSdCard/Musicblee/Over_the_horizone.mp3 this is path of file store in phone