# how to play music on click of an action button

Tags: android

i am trying to play music or mp3 on click of an action button but none is working since most of the tutorials are based on button listeners. i need help regarding how to play music on click of an option menu or action bar menu. Can anyone please help me regarding this problem.

Comment: provide the code and xml you wrote so far for menu

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recommended solution to playing a mp3:

Link: [Simple mediaplayer play mp3 from file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715003/simple-mediaplayer-play-mp3-from-file-path)

```
String filePath = 
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/yourfolderNAme/yopurfile.mp3";
mediaPlayer = new  MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);
mediaPlayer.prepare();   
mediaPlayer.start()
```

and this play from raw folder.

```
 int resID=myContext.getResources().getIdentifier(playSoundName,"raw",myContext.getPackageName());

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(myContext,resID);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
```